# Bootstrap 4 - site.time function?

Tags: bootstrap-4

In the `Pricing` example for `Bootstrap 4` they have this code in the footer:

```
{{ site.time | date: "%Y" }}
```

The page isn't a `php` page, so how is the server/browser interpreting this code and rendering the year?

Comment: can you share the URL of the page?

Comment: @AkberIqbal The example page is here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/pricing/  And the section of code in the html file is `code` <small class="d-block mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-{{ site.time | date: "%Y" }}</small> `code`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the answer to my own question. Apparently the bootstrap examples are built using a site generator. In this case they are using https://gohugo.io/templates/introduction/. The code string is part of their tool set.